# Is it possible to get jQuery function in a JSON response?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a form which i'm sending with jQuery post function to a php script.

The in the php script i do some checkings and send back a response with a formate like so:

```
$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'your id is wrong!'));
die($output);
```

in the page where i have the form i can use a simple way to fire some functions based on the response. for example:

```
if(response.type == 'error'){
output = '<div class="clienConError">'+response.text+'</div>';
$(".results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
}
```

which means if it is the response is set as error type one do this and that...

**My question is:**
Is it possible to send back a jQuery function? so instead of saying: if it's a response set as error type do this. i say never mind what response is it, just do what the response tell you (for example hide some element, inject some html some where and so on... all kinds of jQuery functions).

If it is possible it will give me a few advantages. one of them is the ability to actually hide some jQuery functions (in the php script).

Comment: additionally, you won't _really_ hide them because they will be bounced back to the client in any case.

Comment: but can the user see what i'm sending back? for example if i will send back a response with some text and just setting a that as a value of a jQuery variable for example without using it any where (just for the idea) will the client see the text?

Comment: That's not the way you should be coding. Not at all

Comment: That's not the way you should be commenting. Not at all :) you should explain why you think this idea is bad and make us bad coders smarter :) thanks!

Comment: Everything the browser receives and executes can be read by the client using the developer tools that are included with every browser, so you cannot hide anything using this technique. If you try to hide parts of your code in PHP that way, the only thing you will get is unmaintainable code infrastructure, that will become prone to errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is generally not recommended, it is possible to return JavaScript code from a PHP script, preferably with the appropriate `Content-Type: text/javascript` header.

At client side, you may execute the generated code using `eval` or injecting it in the page via a newly created `<script>` tag.

Dynamic scripts are discouraged for several reasons:

1. Harder to maintain: the generated code is –by essence– not static, and thus you can never see and edit the whole code as with a static file.
2. At best sloppy from the security point of view: allowing execution of arbitrary code is never a good idea, and attackers will more than certainly try to leverage this to perform client side attacks such as XSS.
3. Not friendly towards optimizers: contrary to a whole static script which can be parsed and optimized as soon as the file has finished loading, multiple fragmented bits of script cannot benefit from optimization.

Moreover, attempting to hide client code is a battle already lost. If the code is executed client side, then it is visible client side, period. Any user, and I insist, *any* user, can open the F12 debugger of their browser and place breakpoints or use step-by-step mode. More savvy users might overwrite the `eval` function or hook the `beforescriptexecute` event to inspect what’s going on. And there are even more ways.

The best you can do is obfuscate your code, with possible loss in performance and complexification of your workflow.

Comment: Great answer. thank you very much! i will be happy to hear some more about that 2nd reason but that's more of another google'ling adventure for me now i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could really do this is by returning a javascript expression in text (wrapped in double quotes) in a JSON object. You would then need to eval() the response which isn't great for a variety of reasons - injection, performance, debugging.

I'd suggest against this approach anyway as you are overlapping the boundaries of what a client and server should be doing - tightly coupling both layers.

Comment: Thanks. is it ok if i will ask to explain a little bit more "for dummies style" about the problems with eval() and the overlapping the boundaries thing...?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `eval()` but it is **not recommended** due to performance and security reason. `eval()` executes the argument passed to it. So you can send the jquery function as a string and pass it to `eval()` to execute it on client side.

**Sample Code:**

```js
var command= 'var output = \'<div class="clienConError">Here is the response</div>\';$(".results").hide().html(output).slideDown();'
eval(command);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='results'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. can you explain a little more (or maybe add some links to info) about the eval performance and security problems? also - will the client be able to see the function this way?